# Salesforce Named Credentials - oauth token refresh does not work

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials, refresh-token, sharepoint

I am using Named Credentials to make callouts to a sharepoint system.

Initially, callouts from apex code work fine, until the token expires after 12 hrs. Then I am consistently receiving below error:
UnauthorizedHTTP 401 : {"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. The token is expired."}

The only "workaround" is to reset External Credentials under My Personal Information --> External Credentials by hitting Revoke Access and then Allow Access, things start working  again. Any ideas what the underlying issue could be? Do you see any settings/scope related issue?

Named Credential settings are as follows:

[image: Auth Provider Settings]

[image: External Credentials Settings]

[image: Named Credentials Settings]

[image: Request/response from postman with same setting as in Named Credentials]

Comment: The underlying issue is that the refresh token isn't issued.  Take a look at Sharepoint / Azure docs, figure out the right incantation and then redo your config. A good first step is to implement the entire flow via command-line first.

Comment: @identigral, as suggested, checked the flow with command-line with same settings as configured in Named Creds and refresh token is being issued.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the requests/responses from the command-line

Comment: @identigral, I have added the screenshot.

Comment: It's a 2 step process. Your screenshot shows the 2nd step of the process where the authz code is redeemed.

Comment: Yes @identigral, screenshot is of 2nd step. One thing to note that I had to append  client_id with "@sharepoint tenant id" to make the command line request work. If I do NOT add tenant id then error message is - AADSTS900192: Unable to determine the tenant identifier from the request.

Comment: How do you compare what you've done in Salesforce (2 steps) to a screenshot of 2nd step only?

Comment: @identigral, For step1, I copied "Test-Only Initialization url" displayed under Auth. Provider settings in salesforce. Pasted this in browser address bar, clicked "Trust It" on consent dialog. It returned code along with Callback Url. Used this code for step 2 screenshot attached above.